# How to write a Function in R that takes Excel File Name as argument(without extention) and imports that File

Tags: r, excel, function, import

I have trying many methogs including using "file.paths()" functions etc. but am unable to. It always says that the file "CHCC" for example is not found (even though my file's complete name is CHCC.xlsx)

```
importData <- function(stockName){

path <- paste("~/Individual Technical Indicator's Results/", stockName, ".xlsx", sep = "")

dataFrame <- read_excel(path)

}
```

Comment: You have an apostrophe in a directory name?  Yikes.

Comment: Use the `full.names` argument (set to `TRUE`) to guarantee the directory structure sent to `read_excel` is correct.

Comment: The latest RStudio can import Excel files by clicking in the Files pane. It will then show you the code used for import, which you can copy for your own use either before import or from the history afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shQuote` to properly delimit the path/file name.